# Assign a list to a numpy array column as a repeating set of numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array called `formattedData` which has ~1000 rows and is currently set to contain:

```
-999 -999 -999
-999 -999 -999
...
-999 -999 -999
```

I have another variable called `timeList` which is a list of length 5:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I would like to overwrite the 3rd column in `formattedData` with the data from `timeList` repeated over and over until the end of the array. I know that  `timeList` will always fit into `formattedData` an exact number of times, e.g:

```
-999 -999 1
-999 -999 2
-999 -999 3
-999 -999 4
-999 -999 5
-999 -999 1
-999 -999 2
-999 -999 3
-999 -999 4
-999 -999 5
...
-999 -999 1
-999 -999 2
-999 -999 3
-999 -999 4
-999 -999 5
```

I have tried various things but can't get it to work. Can anyone help point me in the right direction with this?

Thanks!

Comment: hi @IamNotACoderYet! If any one of the solutions below worked for you and if you wish, you might consider accepting them to signal others that the issue is resolved. Otherwise you can provide feedback and they get improved or removed altogether. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, forgot the link to acceptance: [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/791774)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) to repeat your list and then put it into the 3rd column of the array. Number of repetitions is precalculated:

```
num_repeats = len(formattedData) // len(timeList)

to_place = np.tile(timeList, reps=num_repeats)

formattedData[:, 2] = to_place
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY:

```
formatteddata[:, 2] = np.tile(
    timelist, formatteddata.shape[0] // timelist.shape[0])
```